# How to set the overall Grid thumbnail height to be equal?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid of thumbnails. It's coded in `<ul>` as a wrapper and `<li>` for displaying each thumbnails. I have set the following CSS to the `<li>` tag:

```
float: none;
display: inline-block !important;
```

The thumbnails are displaying in a Grid. I have also used Bootstrap classes in `<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">`. As per assigned classes it should display 4 thumbnails per row. But currently it's displaying only 3 thumbnails per row. I searched and found that it's because `<li>`s are given `display: inline-block` and there are line break in HTML after each `<li>` in the HTML file. Please let me know how to display 4 thumbnails per row using `display: inline-block`.

Also if I set the `float: left` for `<li>` then I should give height for each `<li>`. But the images within those `<li>`s are of different size.

The problems are:

1. I want to display 4 columns per row (now only 3 are displaying)
2. I want to set the border-right to cover whole height of the grid row. (Now since height of the `<li>` is according to the height of the thumbnail, the border-right is spanning till half the row for smaller thumbnails.)

Please help me with this.

```css
body {
            background-color: #ddd;
            }

            .list-unstyled {
            background-color: #eee;
            width: 100%;
            }

            .list-unstyled li{
            background-color: #eee;
            float: none;
            display: inline-block !important;  
            /*display: -moz-grid !important;*/
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
            box-sizing: border-box;    
            }

            .list-unstyled li img{
            width: 100%;
            }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
        <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/A-HAPPY-SUNDAY.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/cover17.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/cover1.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary" >Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Bolne-Wali-Ghadi.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cover14.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary" >Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/cover.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Chhoti-Chinti-ki-Badi-Dawat.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cover7.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cover13.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/Fu-ku.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cover8.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li style="" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 product-li">
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="" class="book_image">
                        <a href="#" title=""><img src="http://ebooks.nbtindia.gov.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cover7.jpg" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_title">
                        <h3>Sample Title</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="book_price">
                        <a href="#" title="" class="btn btn-primary">Button</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: You better use flexbox for this job.

Comment: if you want to display it as inline then why are you using ul and li just use divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `display: inline-block !important;` from `.list-unstyled li` and  give `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` to `.list-unstyled` will make it as your expected result.

```
.list-unstyled {
   background-color: #eee;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv1r86vj/)**

**Edit:**

Give `display: flex; align-items: flex-end;` to `.list-unstyled li`

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hv1r86vj/1/)**

Comment: Great, that works Ketan!!! But how to vertically align the thumbnail content to bottom. I tried display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom; for <li>, but it didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of `float: none;` in `.list-unstyled li`

Comment: Bootstrap will add float:left; to <li> as I have added bootstrap classes to li. Since they are of different sizes, they won't display properly in grid. To have them properly display I have to set the height for li. But I can't set the height, they are having dynamic height.

Comment: Go with display: flex on the ul, or use JavaScript to get the height of your li's and return to you the tallest one so you can set all li's to that using jQuery. I recommend going with display: flex. As mentioned by ketan. However, you don't need to remove inline-block !important if it's part of the bootstrap that you need.

Comment: display: flex; has worked for me. Thank you for the reply.